# How to disable JPEG corruption message in OPENCV?

Tags: opencv, libjpeg

I am working with images taken by a high speed IP camera which transmits them through Ethernet port. During transmission, a few bytes are lost or corrupted occasionally without any visual impact. When I load the images in a sequence  using cvLoadImage, frequently a message like "Corrupt JPEG data: Premature end of data segment" or "Corrupt JPEG data: extraneous bytes before marker 0*d9" appears.

I don't want cvLoadImage to display such errors since they are common due to high speed transmission of images. Also printing to console is time-consuming since I might be processing upto 2000 images at a time.

How do I disable these messages. I have the Opencv 2.0 source and can dig into it if I get the right pointer.

**P.S.** I tried looking into grfmt_jpeg.cpp and similar source files but didn't find this error message anywhere.

Comment: Comments in cap_v4l.cpp (in 2.4.7) mention fixes for the error message you mentioned with high speed cameras - possibly this is already in v2.0. However, if you really are using only OpenCV 2.0 it would be worth checking whether upgrading to 2.4.7 fixes the problem.

Comment: There is a cap_v4l.cpp within src/highgui of Opencv 2.0. The comment says "Fix reliability problems with high-resolution UVC cameras on linux.the symptoms were damaged image and 'Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment' on stderr". However the actual error message is not printed here. My plan is to find the code that prints it to stderr and then disable those lines of code. I am looking for performance boost since this error gets printed to console in my console application and slows it down.

Comment: http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~dennismv/corruptjpeg.html This seems like a possible solution, maybe I have to make changes to some code in libjpeg and then recompile it. jerror.h has lines saying JMESSAGE(JWRN_EXTRANEOUS_DATA,"Corrupt JPEG data: %u extraneous bytes before marker 0x%02x"). JMESSAGE(JWRN_HIT_MARKER, "Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment") I will look into it and hopefully let you guys know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I rebuilt opencv with `BUILD_JPEG` `WITH_JPEG` set to true so that opencv uses its own libjpeg rather than using the system one, and with the fprintf in `3rdparty/libjpeg/jerror.c` commented out, which of course disables possibly more important messages than the minor annoyances that can flood stderr:

```
METHODDEF(void)
output_message (j_common_ptr cinfo)
{
  char buffer[JMSG_LENGTH_MAX];

  /* Create the message */
  (*cinfo->err->format_message) (cinfo, buffer);

#ifdef USE_WINDOWS_MESSAGEBOX
  /* Display it in a message dialog box */
  MessageBox(GetActiveWindow(), buffer, "JPEG Library Error",
             MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
#else
  /* Send it to stderr, adding a newline */
  // fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
#endif

}
```

The much quicker option is redirecting the stderr to /dev/null e.g., and even more possibilities for legitimate errors are now unseen:

```
./cpp-example-bgfg_segm -m knn -c 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a nice and neat way of avoiding these error printouts - they originate from the core of libjpeg.

If you do want to dig in and see who is actually emitting the errors, take a look in 3rdparty/libjpeg/. Look at *jerror.h/c*.

**PS.** I think your particular error comes from the **no_more_bytes**-goto-flag in the `jpeg_fill_bit_buffer()` in *jdhuff.c*.